# semantic forms-issue with info tag and page name parameter

Tags: forms, mediawiki, semantics

Been trying to figure out how to automaticly create a page name using the values in a form
been reading this page: 
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Linking_to_forms#The_one-step_process

I cant figure out how to do it, after reading, but i think it`s possible, if anyone that knows how to work with it all the help would be welcomed

Well atm this is what i have

```
<noinclude>
This is the "OARK" form.
To create a page with this form, enter the page name below;
if a page with that name already exists, you will be sent to a form to edit that page.

{{{info page name=<Organizational artifact relation kind[Prefix_1_2]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Is target of reference law 1]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Infix_2_1]>.<Organizational artifact relation kind[Is target of reference law 2]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Sufix_2_1]>}}}

</noinclude><includeonly>
<div id="wikiPreview" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
{{{for template|Organizational artifact relation kind}}}
{| class="formtable"
! Prefix_1_2:
| {{{field|Prefix_1_2}}}
|-
! Unicity 1:
| {{{field|Unicity 1}}}
|-
! Dependency 1:
| {{{field|Dependency 1}}}
|-
! Infix_1_2:
| {{{field|Infix_1_2}}}
|-
! Sufix_1_2:
| {{{field|Sufix_1_2}}}
|-
! Prefix_2_1:
| {{{field|Prefix_2_1}}}
|-
! Unicity 2:
| {{{field|Unicity 2}}}
|-
! Dependency 2:
| {{{field|Dependency 2}}}
|-
! Infix_2_1:
| {{{field|Infix_2_1}}}
|-
! Sufix_2_1:
| {{{field|Sufix_2_1}}}
|-
! Is target of reference law 1:
| {{{field|Is target of reference law 1}}}
|-
! Is target of reference law 2:
| {{{field|Is target of reference law 2}}}
|}
{{{end template}}}

'''Free text:'''

{{{standard input|free text|rows=10}}}

{{{standard input|summary}}}

{{{standard input|minor edit}}} {{{standard input|watch}}}

{{{standard input|save}}} {{{standard input|preview}}} {{{standard input|changes}}} {{{standard input|cancel}}}
</includeonly>
```

Like usual it wont work because i can´t figure out how to write it in the code but the general idea is to grab the values of the template in specific fields and thencreate a page with that name and that page has all the values i filled previous.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only issue is the formatting and placement of your `info` tag. You should have something like:

```
{{{info|add title=Add a match|edit title=Edit a match|page name=Game:<Match[Event]> <Match[Bracket]> <Match[Team A]> v. <Match[Team B]> <unique number>}}}
```

to use your example:

```
{{{info|page name=<Organizational artifact relation kind[Prefix_1_2]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Is target of reference law 1]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Infix_2_1]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Is target of reference law 2]>.
<Organizational artifact relation kind[Sufix_2_1]>}}}
```

and you need to make sure it is in the included form, you currently have it in your `noinclude` section.